C# IHost as an embedded independent context
I use IHost to declare system components (small embedded applications). This allows to isolate services (DI containers), execution context and testing from the main system.
The thing is that the Component entity combines many services (including background ones like IHostedService) and I have not found a better solution (Scoped services did not provide such control).
I have not measured the overhead of this solution, but I would like to receive feedback, criticism and ideas for improvement.
I already have a solution and I look how to improve it.

This is a good way for some condition, but, please share the reason why you use his Ihost as an embedded independent context. If you are running multiple Ihost service may cost more resource.

Hi @BrandoZhang
Sure, IHost "costs" more than a plain\native implementation, but I use it because:

Combine and limit all Component's service in a different context prevent mixing them with the main application.
Each Component can declare only proprietorial services or import some of them from the main app.
Easy to run Unit testing for a Component, because there is possible to "extract" it from the main app (a weak dependency).
There is no big intensity of Components creating

Let's say, it is an attempt to extract big application entities in containers inside the app.
